# add custom cookie in PHP cURL

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm a cURL and PHP newbie. I am writing a script in which I need to create a custom cookie and maybe include it with the cookies that cURL creates. Following advice I found on this site, I've created a cookie like this

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "DOAReferrer==$cookie_header=$cookie_ip_value");`

This appears to create an extra cookie file called "COOKIE_FILE" & my cookie jar file is ignored. How can I add this cookie to my already existing jar?

My code is as follows:

```
$target = ADDR;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "DOAReferrer==$cookie_header=$cookie_ip_value");
$page = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  CURLOPT_COOKIE in correct format :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$cookie_header=$cookie_ip_value");
```

**OR**

add your cookie in **cookies.txt**